# How session sets and unsets in JSF2.0

Tags: session, jsf-2

I want to know about setting and un-setting the session in JSF2.0. Although following some blogs and books (Core JavaServer Faces-3rd Edition), i got to know that using annotation @SessionScoped we can set any manage bean to be in session. I have a loginBean which is @ManagedBean and SessionScoped declared. On the top right corner, my web has login button.
When this session is created (i am not setting it manually, that is why i am confused) and when i gets destroyed? It must be destroyed either by time out or by clicking in logout button only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSF uses the Servlet API under the covers. A session scoped managed bean is in essence set as an attribute of the [`HttpSession`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html). It will be created and set whenever the EL expression referencing the managed bean `#{sessionBean}` is evaluated for the first time. It will be "removed" from the session whenever the session expires (by either a restart of the client or a timeout in the server) or get invalidated. If you let your logout button call [`ExternalContext#invalidateSession()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#invalidateSession%28%29), then the session will be invalidated.

If you're familiar with the basic Servlet API, you should already understand how this all works. For an in-depth explanation of the Servlet's `HttpSession` works under JSF's covers, read this answer: [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909).

Comment: okkkk.... that's interesting...
is invalidating a session and un-setting a session refer to the same thing?

Comment: I think so. At least the phrase "un-setting a session" does technically not make any sense. Most likely you just meant the same but you used wrong terminology.

Answer (score 0):

In jsf 2.0 we can set total class ob as session like i mention

Class_name sm;

ExternalContext extContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext(); extContext.getSessionMap().put("Give name for access this property",sm);

Class_name sm = (Class_name) extContext.getSessionMap().get("Give name for access this property");